# rename files that match strings in a txt file

Tags: awk, rename, mv

I am trying to rename multiple files according to the match to a .txt file
my files are

```
GCF_000698265.1_ASM69826v1_genomic.gff.gz
GCF_000785125.1_ASM78512v1_genomic.gff.gz
GCF_000934565.1_ASM93456v1_genomic.gff.gz
GCF_000963495.1_ASM96349v1_genomic.gff.gz
```

then my tab separated txt file looks like this:

```
GCF_000698265.1_ASM69826v1  Pseudomonas_str1
GCF_000785125.1_ASM78512v1  Pseudomonas_str2
GCF_000934565.1_ASM93456v1  Pseudomonas_str3
GCF_000963495.1_ASM96349v1  Pseudomonas_str4
```

So, for filenames that match the first column of the file, I want to rename the file as the second column.
I was trying to understand how to do it piping mv and awk, but I got lost.
I would like my desired output look like this:

```
Pseudomonas_str1_genomic.gff.gz
Pseudomonas_str2_genomic.gff.gz
Pseudomonas_str3_genomic.gff.gz
Pseudomonas_str4_genomic.gff.gz
```

Can anybody help in this?
I hope I was clear and thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed` and `bash`, assuming the txt file is named 'rename.txt'

```
sed 's/^/mv /' rename.txt | bash
```

Using awk:

```
awk '{system("mv " $1 " " $2)}' rename.txt
```

The key here is to insert "mv " to the beginning of each line and execute.

This last solution does not use any external tool, just bash:

```sh
while read old new; do mv "$old" "$new"; done < rename.txt
```

## Update

Based on Alberto's updated question, here are the changes:

Using sed:

```sh
sed sed 's/^/mv /;s/$/_genomic.gff.gz/' rename.txt | bash
```

Note: The `;s/$/_genomic.gff.gz/` expression said: search the end of the line and append "_genomic.gff.gz" to it. This will work only if you don't have trailing spaces in each line.

Using awk:

```sh
awk '{system("mv " $1 " " $2 "_genomic.gff.gz")}' rename.txt
```

Using Bash:

```sh
while read old new; do mv "$old" "${new}_genomic.gff.gz"; done < rename.txt
```

Comment: Hi @Hai,  thanks a lot. The script works well when the old files are named just exactly as in the rename file. 
However, my files are named as following:

`GCF_001449085.1_ASM144908v1_genomic.gff.gz
 GCF_001746815.1_ASM174681v1_genomic.gff.gz
`
and my file looks like this: 


`GCF_001449085.1_ASM144908v1   Pseudomonas_str1`
`GCF_001746815.1_ASM174681v1    Pseudomonas_str2`

my desired output should look like this


`Pseudomonas_str1_genomic.gff.gz
Pseudomonas_str2_genomic.gff.gz
`
so, can I replace only the part that match? 
thanks!

Comment: Would you please update your question with this comment? I will have an easier time reading the contents of your question than reading the comment here. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Hai Vu, I modified my original question which indeed was incorrect

Answer (score 1):

> was trying to understand how to do it piping mv and awk

You might use AWK to prepare series of commands which then you use as standard input for `bash`. Be warned that your case

```
file1.txt   cat.txt  
file2.txt   dog.txt
file3.txt   fish.txt
file4.txt   mouse.txt
```

is specific as there are not spaces in filenames, if spaces are prohibitied in names then you might simply prepend lines with `mv`  for example if said files is named `renaming.txt` then you might do

```
awk '{print "mv " $0}' renaming.txt | bash
```

however this will fail if there is space in any name. If spaces are allowed then I suggest to use `python` (which is likely installed if you use linux machine) following way, create file `renamer.py` with following content

```
import os
with open("renaming.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        src, dst = line.rstrip().split("\t")
        os.rename(src, dst)
```

where `renaming.txt` is name of file with 2 tab-sheared columns holding current name and desired name then use it as follows

```
python renamer.py
```

How it works: `open`s `renaming.txt` for reading (`r`) for each line it does jettison trailing whitespaces (newlines) and split line at TAB character, 1st part goes to `src`, 2nd to `dst` which are then used in [`os.rename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename) function.

You might select other language for that, preferably which has function for managing files, as this will made developing code for this task easier.

Answer (score 1):

So i create a synthetic test-set that's somewhat sizable, and intentionally only made **1 / 7th** of them match, and there
are no duplicates anywhere, since the synthetic file names are
all based on a unique list of primes, and the files are also in shuffled order.

- **`254923`** `19113991 19113991 test_rename_output_2b.txt`
- **`254923`** `15545069 15545069 test_need_to_rename_2.txt`

```
 1784459  53025088 53025088 test_ref_lookup_2.txt
 2294305  87684148 87684148 total 

# gawk profile, created Thu May 12 03:57:36 2022

    # Rule(s)

     1  FNR == NR { # 1
1784459     do {
1784459         __[$!_]
1784459         getline
        } while (FNR == NR)
    }

     1  FNR != NR { # 1
254923      do {
254923          if ($!_ in __) { 
                    printf("gmv -vn \47%s\47 "\
                                    "\47%s\47 ;\n",$!!NF,$NF)
            }
        } while (getline)
    }
```

The advantage of this solution is that it's already pre-formatted for direct renaming using mv command (sample output) :

```
gmv -vn 'file522111333101.txt' 'newname_799042B2ED_.txt' ;
gmv -vn 'file2011113799793759.txt' 'newname_72518EBA3BC5F_.txt' ;
gmv -vn 'file476743673269.txt' 'newname_6F002325B5_.txt' ;
gmv -vn 'file7979798079897989.txt' 'newname_1C599585EE8185_.txt' ;
gmv -vn 'file211031042203.txt' 'newname_31226E289B_.txt' ;
gmv -vn 'file172888842428207.txt' 'newname_9D3DD209DF2F_.txt' ;
```

To play it safe, I've  pre-pended the `don't overwrite` aka `no-clobber` aka `-n` flag in all the renaming commands, which one can directly send into something light weight like `dash` to execute without requiring further filename manipulation.

Performance is acceptable I suppose -

- `mawk2` took `1.218 secs` to complete all steps (inclusive of writing final output file to disk).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I appreciate the effort in making the script more general, but I would need some more explanations (break-down) on the usage

Comment: [ mawk -- / gawk -be ] "${ code_above }" match_list.txt old_n_new_filenames.txt | [ bash / dash / zsh ]